# Fuchsian Group without fixed points

Tags: geometry, general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I'm searching for a Fuchsian Group without fixed points. (because i need an example for a group $\Gamma$, so that $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is a Riemannian surface, and therefore $\Gamma$ has to be a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ which acts free and properly discontinous, it would be great if $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is compact as well.) 
I found an example in "Svetlana Katok, Fuchsian Groups (Example C in Chapter 4)", but i think this one has fixed points...

Comment: I think page 142 of 'Fuchsian Groups' has a picture of a finite volume example.

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking too hard about this.  For example, the group generated by $z\mapsto z+1$ (where I am considering $z\in\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane), is discrete, fixed point free, and acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$; the quotient is a topological cylinder.

Actually writing down generators a surface group in $SL_2\mathbb{R}$ is usually unilluminating.  Often, one instead regards a closed surface $S$ as obtained by gluing a polygon, and then presents the polygon in $\mathbb{H}^2$ with a right angle at each vertex.  Then [Poincare's polygon theorem](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/hyperbolic-geometry/lecture19.pdf) gives a presentation of the surface group and $\mathbb{H}$ modulo this group is homeomorphic to $S$.

Comment: You may be thinking too hard about this. For example, the group generated by $z \mapsto z$ is discrete, fixed point free, and acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$; the quotient is a topological disc.

Comment: @PastorDoctorMartinSsempa $z\mapsto z$ is fixed-point free?